# Primeira Página em Branco no Adobe

Tags: php, google-chrome, fpdf

Estou usando a classe FPDF v1.6 para gerar relatórios.

Acontece que quando gero os PDFs, no navegador aparece certo. Quando baixo e abro pelo Adobe Reader, a primeira página aparece em branco apenas com um logotipo em cima. As outras páginas aparecem corretamente...

Estou usando a última versão do Chrome.

Segue o código:

```
$pdf = new PDFTrix("P", "mm", "A4");
        $pdf->SetMargins(20, 0, 10);
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
        while ($dados->LeProxReg())
        {
//             consulta quantas bombonas foram coletadas e quantos quilos foram coletados
            $sql->ConsSeleEResultado("Sum(PesoColetado) as PesoTotal, count(*) as Qtd", "ColBom", 
               "IDFecham = " . $dados->Campo("ID") . " and PesoColetado > 0");
            $pdf->AddPage();
            if ($tipo_impr == "P")
            {
                $pdf->SetXY(20, 20);
                $pdf->Cell(20, 20, $pdf->Image(DIR_IMG . "/" . $empresa["NomeLogo"], $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 50), 0, 0, 'L', false );       
                $pdf->SetXY(40, 100);
                $pdf->Cell(150, 150, $pdf->Image(DIR_IMG . "/fundoBrascon.jpg", $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 120), 0, 0, 'L', false );
            }       
            $pdf->SetXY(1, 70);
            $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 36);
//              $pdf->SetTextColor(77, 178, 84);
            $pdf->Cell(210, 10, "CERTIFICADO", 0, 3, "C");
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetXY(1, 100);
            $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 20);
            $pdf->Cell(180, 10, "No " . sprintf("%08s", $dados->Campo("ID")) . "/" . AnoM($dados->Campo("DatFim"))
               , 0, 0, "R");
            $pdf->SetXY(20, 130);
            $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", 14);     
            $text = "Atesto para os devidos fins que a empresa " . $empresa["Nome"] . ", CNPJ: " . 
               FormataCNPJ($empresa["CNPJ"]) . " RLO: " . $dados->Campo("RLO") . ", realizou os serviços de coleta, transporte, " . 
               "tratamento (autoclavagem) e/ou (incineração) e disposição final " . 
               ($sql->Campo("Qtd") > 0 ? "de " . $sql->Campo("Qtd") . " bombonas com " . 
               FormataNumDecVar($sql->Campo("PesoTotal")) ." quilos (Kg) " : "") . "de resíduos " . 
               "do serviço de saúde  do Grupo A/B/E, no " . 
               "período de " . MToB($dados->Campo("DatInicio")) . " à " . MToB($dados->Campo("DatFim")) . 
               ", conforme preconiza a CONAMA-358. referente à nota fiscal " . 
               "Nº: " . $dados->Campo("NumeroNFe") . " emitida para o tomador do serviço, " . $dados->Campo("Nome") . 
               ", CNPJ/CPF: " . ($dados->Campo("EhPessJuridic") == "S" ?
               FormataCNPJ($dados->Campo("CNPJ")) : FormataCPF($dados->Campo("CPF"))) . ", sito a " . 
               $dados->Campo("Endereco") . ", Nº:" . $dados->Campo("Numero") . ", " . $dados->Campo("Bairro") . 
               ", " . $dados->Campo("NomeCidade") . " - " . $dados->Campo("Estado") . ", sendo estes encaminhados " . 
               "para disposição final, na empresa CENTRAL DE TRATAMENTO DE RESÍDUOS LTDA. – CTR-PE, CNPJ: 07.534.580/0001-46, RLO n° 05.15.02.000491-9, com endereço na " . 
               "BR 101 Norte, Km 28.5, – Zona Rural de Igarassu – Pernambuco - PE";
//              $pdf->WordWrap($text,160);
//              $pdf->Write(5, $text);
            $pdf->MultiCell(165, 5, $text, 0, "J");

            $pdf->SetXY(10, 220);
            $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", 12);
            $pdf->Cell(160, 10, ImpDatExt($bd, $empresa["Cidade"], DataAtual()), 0, 0, "R");

            $pdf->SetXY(75, 240);
            $pdf->Cell(40, 40, $pdf->Image("./fotos/" . $dados->Campo("AssResponsavel"), $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 50), 0, 0, 'L', false );
        }
        if(ob_end_clean())
            $pdf->Output("Certificado.pdf", "I");
```

Detalhe que isto só acontece quando entra neste if (Ou seja... no uso das imagens de log e marca d'água):

```
if ($tipo_impr == "P")
```

Caso contrário, roda normalmente!

**RESOLVI PESSOAL:
Removi as imagens de dentro da célula.**

```
if ($tipo_impr == "P")
            { 
                $pdf->SetXY(20, 10);
                $pdf->Image(DIR_IMG . "/" . $empresa["NomeLogo"], 20, 20, 50);      
                $pdf->SetXY(40, 80);
                $pdf->Image(DIR_IMG . "/fundoBrascon.jpg", 40, 80, 120);
            }
```

Comment: no firefox ele tbm abre em branco... em qualquer outro ele abra normal... =//

Comment: so da problema quando entra naquele if que insere a marca dagua e o logo!
realizando uns testes constatei que quando entra no if, se incluo as duas imagens, a primeira predomina e some o resto...comentei a linha da primeira, a segunda imagem (marca dagua) predomina e some o texto, colocando somente a primeira, ela predomina e some o texto! alguem tem alguma ideia? e detalhe que so acontece na primeira pagina do pdf!